# MySQL nested Select BETWEEN multiple rows

Tags: mysql, nested, between

I have 2 tables:
***Table 1*** called calendar and have all dates and days
Example:

```
---------------------
date       | day
---------------------
2013-07-08 | Tuesday
2013-07-09 | Wednesday
```

and so..

***Table 2*** called "events" and have event start dates and end dates
Example:

```
-------------------------------------------
title     | date        | end_date
-------------------------------------------
eventweek | 2013-07-08  | 2013-07-14
```

etc.

Now I need to select the days between those dates which would be:

```
SELECT days
FROM   calendar
WHERE  date BETWEEN
                     (
                     SELECT date
                     FROM   events
                     WHERE  title LIKE %eventweek%)
AND
       (
              SELECT end_date
              FROM   events
              WHERE  title LIKE %eventweek%).
```

Now the problem is when there is multiple "eventweek" titled events like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
title     | date        | end_date
-------------------------------------------
eventweek | 2013-07-08  | 2013-07-14
eventweek | 2014-07-01  | 2014-07-13
```

of course I will get "subquery returns more than 1 row".

Expected results in this example are the days between 2013-07-08 and 2013-07-14 plus the days 2014-07-01 and 2014-07-13 and every future "eventweek" tagged entry.

Btw this gonna be a table view so maybe can't be solved with a loop. Any ideas?

**Thanks a lot** for any suggestion, I will try them all to see the simpler and faster one.

Comment: 8th July was a Monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think between is a good start, this should be better:

```
SELECT c.day
FROM events e
join calendar c on (c.date>=e.date and c.date<=e.end_date)
WHERE e.title = 'eventweek'
```

Comment: Well, this is the accepted answer. The problem was a quite more extended and complex than I used as example but the answer did the work as solution. Thanks !